# CoreData usage in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I use CoreData, use method `addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:url options:options error:&error` to add a DataBase 1, switch user and login, add a DataBase 2, when I write data in DataBase2 but it's still writing in dataBase1, so how to change sqlite file in current `NSManagedObjectContext`?

Comment: Please format the code for readability.  Also provide more details, such as the exact steps you are performing.  Show the code.  Perhaps explain why you would switch persistent stores after the user logs in.

Comment: This is indeed an unusual scenario, but adding a persistent store does not remove the previous one. You may want to consider `removePersistentStore:error:`, though adding the details requested by @Avi would be a good idea.

Comment: NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[docs stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DVBand.sqlite"]];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSPersistentStore *store = [self.persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStoreForURL:url];
    if(![self.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores containsObject:store])
    {
        store = [self.persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:url options:options error:&error];
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `nil` from `configuration:` property and use `storeURL` to give different name to have different file location of the persistent store.
The URl can be obtained like-

```
 NSURL *storeURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSLibraryDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
        storeURL = [storeURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"DB2.sqlite"];
```

Comment: if  a persistentStoreCoordinator add two Database  DB1 and DB2 ,what I should do to  write data in a DB that what I wanted?

Comment: change the `storeURL`